# I'm converting plsql to PostgreSQL how to return raised exception in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I'm converting plsql to PostgreSQL.
In plsql:

```
declare
W_USR_EXCE EXCEPTION;
......
raise W_USR_EXCE;
```

I have converted in PostgreSQL like this

```
     IF (W_DAY_TOTAL_AMT > W_NEW_LIMIT) THEN
            W_ERR_MSG := 'Exceeds Benificiary Limit';
 RETURN EXCEPTION USING ERRCODE = '50011';
```

if "if" condition executed am getting "W_ERR_MSG" message along with that i need EXCEPTION to return

but it is not returning any value.
Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Which language are you using for functions in PostgreSQL? By default there's plpgsql and plain SQL; and there are lots of others which can be installed too.

Comment: am writing function in PostgreSQL

Comment: Always start with the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: PostgreSQL is a DBMS, not a language. It might help if you showed more of your code - it would be easier to figure out what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference you can use the below psudo code to raise any error message in POSTGRESQL :

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Nonexistent ID --> %', user_id
      USING HINT = 'Please check your user ID';
```

follow the link for more details :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html